# I have an error in my while condition, what to do?

Tags: fortran95

I'm getting a lot of trouble in this program
This Fibonacci sequence should stop when the difference between the division of two consecutive numbers and the aurea ratio is smaller than 10e-6.
Unfortunately, the program goes automatically to pause status, so I assume there's something going on in my while condition. Any suggestions?

```
program fibonacci
implicit none
integer::a,b,c,i
real::dif
real,parameter::e=10e-6,aurea=((1+sqrt(5.))/2.)
a=0;
b=1;
i=0;
dif=0;
do while (dif<e)
dif=abs((b/a)-aurea)
if (i==0) then
print*, a
else if (i==1) then
print*,b
else
c=a+b
print*,c
a=b
b=c
end if
end do
pause
end program fibonacci
```

Comment: You should probably initialize `diff`.

Comment: The difference between b and a increases, so b/a also increases, so diff increases each time through the loop. The biggest problem is first time into the loop, a=0, b=1, so b/a = 1/0 which is an invalid operation. The best advice I can give is rethink what you're trying to do, try it out on paper for a few iterations, and then code it.